# How to convert Character Year to SAS date 1/1/Year?

Tags: sas

In Base SAS, how do i convert a character Year (2018) to 01/01/2018 in date format?

```
data date;
length charyear $8.;
charyear='2018';
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, when constructing a date from date parts, you should use SAS MDY function. MDY(month,day,year) returns a numeric date, but you need to convert all arguments to numbers, before using the function.

```
data date;
    length charyear $8.;
    charyear='2018';

    format numDate date9.;
    numDate = mdy(1,1, input(charyear, best.));
run;
```

In your particular case it can be done even easier by using function INPUT with a corresponding date informat:

```
data date;
    length charyear $8.;
    charyear='2018';

    format numDate date9.;
    numDate = input("01JAN" || charyear, date9.);
run;
```